# Is the formula for Schrodinger's equation on Wikipedia incorrect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation

On Wikipedia, the SWE contains a term called reduced mass. After consulting several peers, no one knows what this has to do with SWE. What we do know is that the "effective" mass is sometimes used to represent the mass of an electron. But no mention of reduced mass is found in literature on microscopic physics

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Google "reduced mass".

Comment: Or click the link for "reduced mass" directly below the equation in question

Comment: Just to make it explicit: The equation is *correct*. For a 1-particle problem, $\mu=m$ anyways.

Comment: @Danu So why bother with the $\mu$?  I think the text is misleading.

Comment: @garyp Technically, it matters in e.g. the treatment of the hydrogen atom or, more importantly, in a Physics GRE favorite: positronium. EDIT: I see that you are also aware of this cf. your answer.

Comment: Why the down votes?  The wording on the Wikipedia page is not at all clear.

Comment: @garyp the wording is very clear about linking to the page on reduced mass. An asker who can't be bothered to show that they clicked that link (much less Googled the term) is inviting deserved downvotes.

Comment: @DavidZ I see two questions in the OP:  1.) what is reduced mass, and here I agree with you.  But 2.) why $\mu$ in the SE, and here I think the Wikipedia article stumbles, and the OP request for clarification is a valid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia page appears to be a little confused on this point.   It claims to provide the Schrodinger Equation for a charged particle in an electric field.    One might infer from the wording that the equation to follow is for a fixed, static electric field set up by fixed external charges.

What actually follows, however, is the Schrodinger equation for a system of two charged particles that mutually interact, and in which both particles are free to move.  The hydrogen atom, for example.   In such a case, the dynamics can be separated into *motion of the center of mass* and *motion of the reduced mass*.  This is equally true in classical mechanics.

As others have noted, for a one-particle system, $\mu=m$.  So why bother writing $\mu$ for a one-particle system?

I wouldn't say the equation there is *wrong* but I would say that the text around it can be misleading.  As others have suggested, ask google about "reduced mass".

Comment: *...why bother writing $\mu$...* probably the same reason they don't explicitly write the potential for the electric field in the TDSE: generality.

Comment: @KyleKanos Writing $\mu$ implies and restricts to a two-body interaction.  To me it looks less general than writing $m$ and restricting to static potentials.

Comment: @garyp you are exactly right, Wikipedia is the main problem. In introductory QM all we talk about is single electron, interaction is rarely done. Further more, even if interaction is done, I do not ever recall having to calculate this reduced mass quantity, hence my unfamiliarity

Comment: @garyp also regrettable to see veterans giving non-answers these days, reflects quite badly on them

Answer (score 2):

The [reduced mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_mass) is used where we are modelling a two (or more) body system by a single body. It isn't just used in quantum mechanics - you'll find it used in classical mechanics as well.

For example, suppose we are modelling a hydrogen atom. We normally think of the electron as orbiting the proton, but actually both orbit their mutual centre of mass. This makes the hydrogen atom a complicated two body problem and very difficult to solve. However we can represent this as a single *electron* orbiting a fixed proton, but we have to change the *electron* mass slightly to take into account that the proton is moving as well. Instead of the normal electron mass we use the reduced mass of the electron-proton system.